# TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get this error-

> TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined

With the following JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#role").on('keyup', function(){

        var error = false;
        if ($("#role").val() == ""){  
        if($(this).attr("id") == "role"){
            $("#roleError").html("Role is required");
            $("#role").css("border","1px solid red");
        }
        error = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my html code-

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="pull-left" for="role">ROLE</label>
    <input type="text" name="role" class="form-control grn-text-input"
           id="role" ng-model="role.name" placeholder="Manager"  required/>
    <span id="roleError" class="pull-left errormsg"></span> 
</div>
```

Any ideas why I get such error?

Comment: typo `$("#role").val()`

Answer (score 3):

The element with id `Ro` doesn't exist, so this code fails:

```
$("#ro").val()
```

I assume this has to be

```
$("#role").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

Typing mistake on this line -

```
if ($("#ro").val() == ""){
```

Change it to -

```
if ($("#role").val() == ""){
```

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#role").on('keyup', function(){

check this out

```
 var error = false;
            if ($("#role").val() == ""){  
            if($(this).attr("id") == "role"){
                $("#roleError").html("Role is required");
                $("#role").css("border","1px solid red");
            }
            error = true;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          $("#ro").val()
```

This error comes because element with Id ro doesn't exist

Change this to #role

```
        $("#role").val()
```