# place data-user after click select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a mention system using jquery. I have a problem with replacing data-name after click.

I have try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("body").on("click", ".select", function(){
      var username = $(this).attr("data-user");
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   $('.vals'+id).val($('.vals'+id).val()+ username+ ' '); 
   });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="postit tag_1">
    <textarea name="" id="1" cols="60" rows="3" class="addpost vals1" placeholder="Start to type with @joh and click John Dow"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="postit">
    <div class="select" id="1" data-user="john">John Doe</div>
    <div class="select" id="1" data-user="justin">Justin Doe</div>
    <div class="select" id="1" data-user="ketty">Ketty Perry</div>
    <div class="select" id="1" data-user="adele">Adele</div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Please try this for better understand my problem. Write this text `@joh` and click the John Doe . After you click the text changing like this `@johjohn` it should be `@john` after clicked `John Doe` because of the `data-user="john"`. I have try to do it like this: `$('.vals'+id).val($('.vals'+id).val()+ username+ ' ');` but it didn't worked. What i am missing here anyone can help me please ?

Comment: You have to clear whateevr you have typed

Comment: $('.vals'+id).html();

Comment: You are appending the data from data-user to the current value of the textarea. What is the expect behaviour? Note that id's should be unique.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Id is for a textarea not a user id.

Comment: You have 4 times a div with the same id `<div class="select" id="1"`

Comment: @Thefourthbird  did you see `vals1` in textare class that id 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html contains 5 times the same id: `id="1"` but id's should be unique.
You might do this without using the id's for select and for example only use an id for `textarea`.

Split the string by space and check if the last word you typed starts with with the value from `data-user`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").on("click", ".select", function() {
    var textArea = "#" + $(this).closest("[data-textarea]").data("textarea");
    var words = $(textArea).val().split(' ');
    if (words.length > 0) {
      var username = $(this).attr("data-user");
      if (words[words.length - 1].startsWith('@')) {
        words[words.length - 1] = "@" + username;
        $(textArea).val(words.join(' '));
      }

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="postit tag_1">
    <textarea name="" id="textarea1" data-textarea="textarea1" cols="60" rows="3" class="addpost vals1" placeholder="Start to type with @joh and click John Dow"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="postit" data-textarea="textarea1">
    <div class="select" data-user="john">John Doe</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="justin">Justin Doe</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="ketty">Ketty Perry</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="adele">Adele</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But i have many textarea in one page. The textarea id is 1. That is why i used to id 1 for all select class div. When i click the data-user then textarea id 1 is change other textare ids are different.

Comment: @Azzo You might use a setup like this where you use another data attribute to specify which textarea goes with which set of divs https://jsfiddle.net/vyck489m/

Comment: i get this error from developer console `TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined`  from this line : `var words = $("#textarea").val().split(' ');`

Comment: Did you add the id to the textarea like `  <textarea name="" id="textarea" cols="60" rows="3" class="addpost vals1" placeholder="Start to type with @joh and click John Dow"></textarea>` [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36329086/typeerror-val-is-undefined-in-jquery) might be helpful.

Comment: Did you tryed your demo page ? There is a problem also.

Comment: Can you be more specific? When I load https://jsfiddle.net/vyck489m/  in Chrome Version 71 or FF 63 on a mac I don't see an error. What is not working or what kind of error do you see?

Comment: I am using imac and firefox giving an error don't try chrome i get an error on this line`var words = $("#textarea").val().split(' ');` and error is `TypeError: $(...).val(...) is undefined` also is there anyway to do it `class="vals1"` without `id="textarea"` ?

Comment: also i am using FF 64.0

Comment: And you also added `data-textarea="textarea1` to `<div class="postit" data-textarea="textarea1">`? Can you send a fiddle of the code you are using?

Comment: please look at this i used your answer from here: https://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/BvRzmw?editors=1010

Comment: You forgot to update `id="textarea`"` to `id="textarea1"` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOWgZK?editors=1010

Comment: after i click the text nothing happened ?

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="postit tag_1">
    <textarea name="" id="1" cols="60" rows="3" class="addpost vals1" placeholder="Start to type with @joh and click John Dow"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="postit">
    <div class="select" data-user="john">John Doe</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="justin">Justin Doe</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="ketty">Ketty Perry</div>
    <div class="select" data-user="adele">Adele</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var postit_textarea = $("#1");
   $("body").on("click", ".select", function(){
      var username = $(this).attr("data-user");

        $(postit_textarea).val('@' + $(this).attr('data-user')); 
   });
  });
```

JSFIDDLE

```
https://jsfiddle.net/guruling/9g5u0c2q/4/
```

If you have a single Textarea, then no need get the ID for the each 'select' item click.

Comment: your anser working just for one click if i continue to write some other text from textarea then click another data-user then all other words are deleting.